# Не могу разобраться с сортировкой посредством вставок и слияния

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть код, но никак не могу понять работает ли он правильно, может кто сделает

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
void insertion_sort(double* array, int l, int r)
{
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
    {
        double tmp = array[i];
        int j = i;
        while ((j = 1) && (array[j - 1] > tmp))
        {
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        array[j] = tmp;
    }
}
 
void merge(double* arr, double* temp, int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    int k = l;
    while ((i <= m) && (j <= r))
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j])
        {
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
 
    for (; j <= r; j++, k++)
        temp[k] = arr[j];
 
    for (; i <= m; i++, k++)
        temp[k] = arr[i];
 
    for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        arr[i] = temp[i];
}
 
void mergesort(double* arr, double* temp, int l, int r, int threshold)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        if ((r - l) <= threshold)
            insertion_sort(arr, l, r);
        else
        {
            int m = (l + r) / 2;
            mergesort(arr, temp, l, m, threshold);
            mergesort(arr, temp, m + 1, r, threshold);
            merge(arr, temp, l, m, r);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    double array[100];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
 
    double* temp = new double[100];
    mergesort(array, temp, 0, 99, 10);
    delete[] temp;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во вставках ошибка

```
while ((j = 1)...
```

Это же вызовет сразу остановку. Нужно

```
while ((j > 0)...
```

В слиянии приличней будет сделать так (на основной результат сортировки это не влияет)

```
if (arr[i] <= arr[j])
```